# SQL Query 2 rows and display only once that have same value

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, rows

I have these 2 tables, BOOK and REVISION, sort of like this:

```
Book
Book_ID  |  Book_Name |
======================
1        |      Book 1|
2        |      Book 2|
3        |      Book 3|
4        |      Book 4|
```

```
Revision
Rev_Book_ID  |  Date_Modified |
===========================
1            |      10/1/2012   |
2            |      10/3/2012   |
2            |      10/5/2012   |
4            |      10/6/2012   |
```

When a book is being modified the book_id of the book will be save in Revision Table. If that book is being revised again it will add another row of that certain book. In my SQL query the result is this it display the 2 revisions of the book.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT book.Book_ID, book.Book_Name, Revision.Rev_Book_ID  from Book INNER JOIN Revision ON book.Book_ID=Revision.Rev_Book_ID
```

And also on the Revision result (PHP problem) how could I achieve that if the book is revised twice it will display 2 revisions or 3 if 3 revisions made, I know this is an if and else but don't have an idea how to make that.

```
My Result:

Book ID   |  Book Name     | Revisions        |
==============================================
1         |     Book 1     | 1 Revision       | 
2         |     Book 2     | 2 Revision       | 
2         |     Book 2     | 2 Revision       | 
3         |     Book 3     | No Revision      | 
4         |     Book 4     | 1 Revision       |
```

```
Want Result
Book ID   |  Book Name     | Revisions        |
==============================================
1         |     Book 1     | 1 Revision       | 
2         |     Book 2     | 2 Revision       | 
3         |     Book 3     | No Revision      | 
4         |     Book 4     | 1 Revision       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by book_id and select only these rev_book_ids that == to MAX(Rev_Book_ID)
Generaly you want to agreagete data per book.
here is mysql spec: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html
it should give you many ideas

Answer (score 0):

For each Book, you the number of revisions (`COUNT(Date_Modified)`):

```
   SELECT Book_ID, Book_Name, COUNT(Date_Modified) AS "Revisions"
     FROM Book
LEFT JOIN Revison
       ON Book_ID = Revision_Book_ID
 GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks this query works. However this part "COALESCE(MAX(Date_Modified), 'No Revision') AS "Revisions" i'm thinking it will show how many revisions made but its not showing up. Or my understanding on this one is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to get rid of the duplicates:

```
SELECT book.Book_ID, book.Book_Name, Revision.Rev_Book_ID from Book 
INNER JOIN Revision ON book.Book_ID=Revision.Rev_Book_ID GROUP BY book.Book_ID
```

Comment: Yes This query works. I really want to get rid of that duplicates. On php side. On the Revision result (this is a PHP problem) how could I achieve that if the book is revised twice it will display 2 revisions or 3 if 3 revisions made, I know this is an if and else but don't have an idea how to make that.